# how to calculate running time of algorithm for this simple modulus operation?

Tags: computational-complexity

With "n" being any positive integer, how many times the statement of while loop will be run, related to "n" please?

```
while(n%2 == 0) n=n/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primes other than $2$ don't matter at all.  Just try it with the numbers from $10$ through $16$ and you will probably see a pattern.

Comment: It will be log2(n) right?

Comment: It will be no more than that, but it could be much less.